# Python ctypes.CDLL object destruction ordering upon sys.exit

Tags: python, garbage-collection, ctypes, z3

I'm currently facing a problem with a CDLL object that vanishes while it is still needed. The code below loads my DLL into the global `_lib` (for the curious, it's [libz3.dll](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3)), declares some of the DLL functions, then creates a Ctx object, which calls out to the CDLL in its constructor and destructor.

```
import sys, os, ctypes

class NC(ctypes.c_void_p):
  def __init__(self, c): self._as_parameter_ = c

_lib = ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join(os.path.realpath('.'), 'libz3.dll'))
_lib.Z3_mk_context_rc.restype = NC
_lib.Z3_mk_context_rc.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
_lib.Z3_del_context.argtypes = [NC]

class Ctx:
    def __init__(self):
        global _lib
        # self.lib = _lib
        self.nctx = _lib.Z3_mk_context_rc(0)
        assert _lib is not None, "in Ctx.__init__"

    def __del__(self):
        global _lib
        assert _lib is not None, "in Ctx.__del__" # fails frequently
        _lib.Z3_del_context(self.nctx)
        # self.lib = None

c = Ctx()
assert _lib is not None, "global"
sys.exit(1)
```

The symptom I'm experiencing is that the assertion in `Ctx.__del__` fails frequently (but not always), while the others never fail. This is also the case if I keep a reference to `_lib` in `Ctx.lib`.

In this example the symptom is easy to fix, by being nice and deleting the `c` (e.g. `del c`, `c = None` or by wrapping it in a `with` statement). In general however, none of these solutions are satisfactory, as users of libz3.dll can not be expected to always clean up all their objects nicely before Python's GC kicks in.

Is there a way to tell Python not to set `_lib` to `None` until it really isn't needed anymore?

Comment: Typically one would store a reference to `_lib` or the function as a default argument, e.g. `def __del__(self, Z3_del_context=_lib.Z3_del_context)`.

Comment: You don't have to declare variables as `global` if you aren't rebinding them. The compiler classifies a name as global if it isn't locally assigned.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting idea! It works for this small example and I think it may be easy enough to apply on the larger scale too.